Finding the probability of a randomly chosen $3$ digit number having exactly two identical digits
A $3$-digit number is being chosen by random such that the digits are chosen from the digits $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ and $5$.
What is the probability

To get a number with even digits only?
To get a number in which only the first digit is even?
To get a number in which only one digit is even?
To get a number in which at least two digits are even?
To get a number in which all digits are identical?
To get a number in which only two digits are identical?

I have solved all but the last one. I would appreciate some assistance with it, and I'll put my answers to the rest in case I got something wrong.
$$\begin{align*}
\Pr(A_1)&=\frac{2\cdot2\cdot2}{5\cdot5\cdot5}=\frac{2^3}{5^3}=0.064\\
\Pr(A_2)&=\frac{2\cdot3\cdot3}{5^3}=0.144\\
\Pr(A_3)&=3\cdot\frac{2\cdot3\cdot3}{5^3}=0.432\\
\Pr(A_4)&=\frac{2^3}{5^3}+3\cdot\frac{2\cdot3\cdot3}{5^3}=0.352\\
\Pr(A_5)&=5\cdot\frac{5\cdot1\cdot1}{5^3}=0.2\\
\end{align*}$$
One more comment: I can't use random variables.

Consider the complement. If not exacty 2 digits are identical then either none are the same or all three are the same.

For 5) why did you multiply by $5$?  There are 5 choices for the one digit so there are five such numbers so the probability is $\frac 5{5^2} = 0.04$.  You can calculate the either as $5$ choices for the first digit and one of the other two as $\frac {5\cdot 1\cdot 1}{5^3}$ or as $5$ choices for what the same digit is and then one choice for each of the three digits as $5\cdot \frac {1\cdot 1\cdot 1}{5^3}$.   But $5\cdot \frac {5\cdot 1\cdot 1}{5^3}$ is a strange mish-mash.

As for 6.  There is $5$ choices for which digit is paired and $4$ choice for what the single digit is.  There are ${3\choose 2}$ poisitions to place the paired digits and ${1 \choose 1}$ to place the single (or equiv. ${3\choose 1}$ positition to choose the single and ${2\choose 2}$ to place the pair).  Thus there are $5\cdot 4 \cdot 3$ such numbers. [In your style $3\cdot \frac {5\cdot 1 \cdot 4}{5^3}$... if that makes things easier.]

Your number is of the form $aab$, $aba$ or $baa$, where $a$ and $b$ are distinct. Choose $a$ in $5$ ways, then $b$ in $4$ ways, and so the total number of numbers satisfying the required criterion is $5\cdot4\cdot3=60$ and so
$$\boxed{\Pr(A_6)=\frac{60}{125}=0.48}$$
Hope this helps. :)

I'm explaining this by "general principle of counting". Take 3 spaces
$$ -  \ \ -\ \ -$$
Ways of pairing 2 numbers:-
Say we are taking two $5$s, and we'll keep one fixed and let one move. Keeping one fixed in the first box,there are such $2$ possible arrangements of two $5$s. Now if we fix $5$ in the second block,it gives us $1$ last possible arrangement.
Thus total possible arrangements$=2+1=3$.
This can happen for all five digits, so total possible ways of pairing$=15$
In a specific instance, say for a specific pair of two digits, we get $4$ possible numbers.
Thus total possible numbers with only two digits repeating $=4×15=60$.
Total possible numbers altogether $=5^3$
Thus probability $=\frac{60}{5^3}=0.48$
I'm giving a general formula. I explained the pairing process for simplifying the general formula actually. If there are $n$ boxes  then possible instances in which each digit can pair twice is $$(n-1)+(n-2)+\cdots+2+1=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
Thus for $m$ digits, possible pairings are $\frac{mn(n-1)}{2}$.
Keeping two digits fixed, possible arrangements for other digits is $^{m-1}P_{n-2}=\frac{(m-1)!}{(m-n+1)!}$
Thus total possible $n$ digit numbers having two digits repititions made from $m$ digits is $=\frac{mn(n-1)}{2}×\frac{(m-1)!}{(m-n+1)!}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}×^mP_{n-1}$
For $m=5,n=3,$ we get our answer as $60$
